# check memory leaks of c code in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, memory-leaks

I am writing an iPhone App which contains part of C,C++ code.
I allocate memory using malloc() and calloc().

How can i check memory leaks in this part of code using Xcode profile.

Can anyone please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Leaks` and `Static memory analyser` to detect leak/static memory loopholes in code with Xcode.

Leaks - http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Static memory analyser - http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#featuredarticles/StaticAnalysis/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that the allocated memory is deallocated using the free() method.

After using "malloc and calloc" to allocate memory is important for freeing up the allocated memory when finished with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Instruments](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) to find the leaks using the *Leaks* profile.

Here's a [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2696/how-to-debug-memory-leaks-with-xcode-and-instruments-tutorial) by Ray Wenderlich.